# Unable to cast EntityEntry current value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the same method in EF 6 and working just fine, but using EF core v1.1.1 is with method throwing an exception like this. Please take a look.
[image]

```
     public virtual T Update(T obj)
    {
        try
        {
            if (null == obj) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj));

            _context.Set<T>().Attach(obj);

            var entry = _context.Entry(obj);

            foreach (var property in entry.OriginalValues.Properties)
            {
                var current = entry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(property.Name); // <-- error occurring this line. If i set the generic type to specific like int,string etc the code work for the specific type only but if i set to object won't work.
                entry.Property(property.Name).IsModified = current != null;
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();

            //Detached the current context to get changes value
            _context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Detached;

            return obj;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.Write(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use indexer to get property value without cast:

```
var current = entry.CurrentValues[property.Name];
```

Primary key property should be excluded from foreach loop. Something like:

```
if (property.Name == "Id") continue;
```

Should work. Otherwise you'll get 
`InvalidOperationException`:

> 'The property 'Id' on entity type 'Foo' is part of a key and so
>   cannot be modified or marked as modified.'